# Discard local git changes when remote commit&push

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new in Git and have some ununderstadable problem. 
On my server MS WIN Server (Local LAN) is installed central repos and each developer has cloned that repos. We are using SmartGit as GUI.
On server (central repos) there are no development or change of files.
When some of developer change some files and commit&push them, it look everything goes right away. 
But on central repos (on server) those changes are not applayed on any file. Instead I have to "discard" changes on server (meaning server's copy) if I want commited changes come to server. Also for other developers changes are not seen until I do "discard".

I don't know if this behavior normal, but for me is a bit strange.

Each developer has defined local repos as well as central, but on central repos I did not defined developer's repositories. (may be that is a problem???)

I tried `git reset --hard`, `git clean -df` as well as other similar commands on server git bash, but nothing help.

Any clue if hook can help automaticaly discard local changes on server when new commit&push? Or any other solution...? Thanks!

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you refer to with certain statements. First: take care that developers do _not_ create "own repositories", but clone the shared one. Further that they set the correct upstream repository in their local clone so that a push to the remote repository actually is pushed upsteam. Also take care not to confuse changes in separate branches. In general it might make more sense to ask your question in a forum dealing with that GUI you use, since it appears that you are not struggling with git issues, but GUI issues.

Comment: It might make sense for all of you to first get a feeling for `git` using the normal command line client. The _huge_ advantage of command line clients (in general, not specific to a certain software) is that you know _exactly_ what you actually do, what is actually happening and what the actual result is. There is no GUI or frontend between you and the real logic which often makes things much more complex and introduces new sources of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A central repository where people push into should be setup as a bare repository, without any worktree. Otherwise you cannot e. g. push to the checked out branch. Git will prevent this. If you also want the current code on some central location you should have an additional repository that clones from that central repository and install some hook to the central repository that triggers the other one to get the latest changes or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps and verify one by one:

1. Just as arkascha and Vampire advised, it’s better to **use git command line** (git bash) directly and each developer only need to use `git clone <central repo path>` to **clone the repo to their local machines** (this is very important)
2. Each developer makes changes on their local machines, and then commit changes
3. Before push to central repo, please double check if the remote repo is the central repo by `git remote -v`. if it is, then push the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for tips...

As I start work with git less than two month ago, I had studied an available books, tutorials as well as youtube channels. I assumed bare repos is not solution for me because I liked to use git repository also as backup copy on server. When I installed repos and did not find copy of files in it and I assume  (as less experience) it is a wrong way, so I have used a regular repos.

Today I configure bare repos for central repos on server, then config a regular repos for backup copy and repositories for each developer. Now it work like charm. Local repo wait about 3min to detect change from central repos.

Once again, thank you for tips.

PS
Gui interface work well, and there was no problem there.